# Configuring for babel.config.js

Tags: react-native, babeljs, expo

I'm relatively new to Expo and React Native. Have been facing problems in using absolute paths while importing the modules. Was reading on how to implement this plugin but I am unable to use it properly since it has only instructions for `.babelrc`. I did almost everything found on different threads regarding this but still, I am unable to use it properly. In my expo project, I also do not have any `.babelrc` file instead I have `babel.config.js` file.

I am trying to convert this code for `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-jsx-source",
        ["module-resolver", {
          "root": ["./src"]
        }]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

To this for `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check the configuration:

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "extends": "./babel.config.js"
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = (api) => {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    "env": {
      "development": {
        "plugins": [
          "transform-react-jsx-source",
          ["module-resolver", {
            "root": ["./src"]
          }]
        ]
      }
    },
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo']
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should .babelrc and babel.config.js files be located? And does babel.config.js need to be referenced/linked anywhere?

Comment: Usually in the root of your project, for more details check the official documentation https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files